# Cannot convert the output of readFile into List for iteration

Tags: go-templates, helmfile, sprig-template-functions

I am using [helmfile](/questions/tagged/helmfile) for my helm releases.

I have a yaml file **projects.yaml**

```yaml
# projects.yaml
- yako
- pera
- okta
```

In **values.yaml.gotmpl**, i want to iterate thru the content of **projects.yaml** :

```yaml
# values.yaml.gotmpl
{{ $projects := readFile 'projects.yaml' }}
{{ range $_, $project := $projects }}
   # do something with $project . e.g: tpl (readFile 'proj-config.yaml') (dict $name $project)
{{ end}}
```

Unfortunately , i got this error :

```
failed to render [values.yaml.gotmpl], because of template: stringTemplate:60:41:
 executing "stringTemplate" at <$projects>: range can't iterate over projects:
- yako
- pera
- okta
```

I made a lot of blind attempts to make it work :

- `{{ range $_, $project := $projects | fromYaml }}`
- `{{ range $_, $project := $projects | toYaml }}`
- `{{ range $_, $project := $projects | list }}`

No way

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ $projects := readFile "./projects.yaml"}}
{{ range $_, $project := get "projects" $projects }}
    {{ $project.attr1 }}
{{end}}
```